# Proof using self-adjoint property

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V \;$  be an inner product space over a field $\Bbb{F}$
 and let $T:V\to V$ be a self-adjoint linear map. Prove that
$V = \operatorname{ker}(T)\oplus\operatorname{im}(T)$.

All I can think of is the definition of self-adjoint i.e. $T=T^*$ or $\left<T(v_1)|v_2\right>=\left<v_1|T^*(v_2)\right>\quad v_1,v_2\in V\quad$ and the identity  $\operatorname{ker}{T}^∗ = \operatorname{im}{T}^⊥$.

Comment: Something to keep in mind: Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional inner product spaces over $F$ (where $F = \mathbb R$ or $F = \mathbb C$).  An important (and easy) theorem says that the orthogonal complement of $\text{ker}(T)$ is $\text{im}(T^*)$, where $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that ${\rm dim}\ im(T) + {\rm dim}\ ker(T)=n$. So we have a claim : $$ im(T)\cap ker(T)=\{ 0\}$$

Assume that $Tx=v\neq 0\in im(T)\cap ker(T)$. Then $$ 0=( x,Tv)=(Tx,v)=(v,v) $$ 
Contradiction.